# When looking at the address of a FILE stream, why is the address so much different than that of the original pointer?

Tags: c++, pointers

Pardon my absolute lack of any understanding here, just diving into C++. So essentially I just wanted to see if I could figure out how to use putc to properly write characters to a file. I wanna make sure I'm understanding every step of the way.

Now, when looking at the address spaces used when I originally declared the pointer for the file, and after passing the pointer to a different function that would write the stream to a file I noticed the address spaces are completely different, even in length, than that of the address space of the original function. Still trying to completely wrap my head around pointers but it's hard without any intervention to tell you where you are misinterpretting things, and I know I have to be. Here is the code, dont mind the fact I'm doing it in Qtcreator. Links help but please don't just copy pasta some C++ info page on pointers. I've read it.

```
#include <QCoreApplication>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <iostream>
#include <fstream>
using namespace std;

void stream_writer(FILE & stream)
{
    int     c1='A',
            c2='B',
            c3='C',
            nl='\n';

    cout << &stream << endl;
    putc(c1, &stream);
    putc(nl, &stream);
    cout << "written to testfile" << endl;
    fclose(&stream);
    putc(c2, stdout);
    putc(c3, stdout);
    putc(nl, stdout);
}

int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
    QCoreApplication a(argc, argv);

    FILE* testfile;
    testfile = fopen("testfile.txt", "wt");
    if (testfile != NULL )
    {
        cout << &testfile << endl;
        cout << testfile << endl;
        stream_writer(*testfile);
    }
    else
    {
        cout << "Unable to open file\n";
    }

    return a.exec();
}
```

An example of my console output after running the code:

> 0x7ffff6aed478
>   0x138a200
>   0x138a200
>   written to testfile
>   BC

Comment: Stack and dynamically allocated pointer addresses may differ widely, yes.

Comment: What is it that you find strange? `&testfile` is the address of your `FILE*` variable, while both `testfile` and `&stream` are the address of the `FILE` object that it points to. (You're also not passing a pointer to the function, you're passing a reference.)

Comment: Why are you ever print pointers? What kind of information do you want to extract? How on earth have you arrived fron putc to pointers? In C++ you need pointers *very* rarely, so your time would be better spent learning other stuff.

Comment: Also you do want to use `std::fstream`. Don't mix C and C++. They're two different languages.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`cout << &testfile << endl;`   is printing the address of the FILE pointer itself: 0x7ffff6aed478

`cout << testfile << endl;` is printing the address that the pointer *points* to: 0x138a200

Memory at address 0x7ffff6aed478 is where the FILE pointer is stored, and it has the value of 0x138a200.

Memory at address 0x138a200 is where the actual FILE object is allocated, and the values here correspond to data in struct FILE{...}

`stream_writer(*testfile);` You're dereferencing to get the FILE object, passing it by reference to stream_writer(). `cout << &stream << endl;` You then are printing the address of the same FILE object again. Hence the third line of output is 0x138a200

Comment: You're welcome! As for why one address has 12 hex characters 0x7ffff6aed478 and the other 8: I don't know for sure but I suspect that fopen() as a low-level function allocates the FILE object in a 32-bit memory space (backward compatibility with older systems, maybe?) whereas your FILE pointer, being a local variable on the stack, ends up with a more 'modern' 64-bit address

Answer (score 2):

```
void stream_writer(FILE & stream)
```

Here you are receiving a reference to a `FILE` object.

```
cout << &stream << endl;
```

Here you are printing the address of a `FILE` object, via a reference.

```
FILE* testfile;
```

Here you are declaring a pointer to `FILE`.

```
cout << &testfile << endl;
```

Here you are printing the value of the pointer.

```
stream_writer(*testfile);
```

Here you are passing the *dereferenced* pointer as an object reference to the called function.

It would be surprising if all of these had the same value.

Your expectations are misplaced.